# Free RTF to PDF .NET component or tool?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, rtf

I am trying to convert a RTF file to a PDF. All tools I found so far cost a lot of money. Is there a tool which I could call or component I could use which converts existing RTF files to PDFs? If its a tool, it should have command line support so I can call it from the code. I am using C#...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class to do this using the Office Interop assemblies. If you have MS Word installed on the machine executing the code, this works well.
http://brandonzeider.me/2010/microsoft-net/convert-word-to-pdf/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iTextSharp can't convert RTF to PDF, but it seems it can convert HTML to PDF. Maybe you can convert your RTF to HTML and next give it to iTextSharp. There is a free RTF to HTML tools in Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conversion in two steps:

1. Parse the RTF data
2. Write the PDF document

For the first step I have written [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx) library.
For the second step I have used a commercial product, but any open source library should also work.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.com/) to create pdf documents.

Comment: Yeah, but not to create PDF from RTF documents...