# Error in pdf generated using File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, byteData)

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, pdf-generation, arrays, richedit-control

I am trying to generate pdf file using Byte Array.
The code is used is:

```
Public Sub SavePdf(ByVal bytes() As Byte)
    Dim filePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ClientBin/file1.pdf")
    Dim byteData() As Byte = bytes
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath,byteData)
End Sub
```

The byte array is generated using richEditControl. The code is as follows:

```
 Public Sub generateByte_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    ms.Flush()
    richEditControl1.SaveDocument(ms, DocumentFormat.Rtf)
    client.SavePdf(ms.ToArray())
    MessageBox.Show("FileSaved")
End Sub
```

The file so generated can't be open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think .Rtf ([Rich Text Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)) data is equivalent to .Pdf ([Portable document format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format)).

It appears you are using the DevExpress RichEditControl which doesn't appear to support saving PDF files directly, see the documentation for available [document formats](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraRichEditDocumentFormatMembersTopicAll).

I'd recommend either saving the RTF data with the .Rtf extension and use an RTF to PDF document converter after writing, or using a Pdf document writer library like [PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/).

To convert a .Rtf file to .Pdf you could either [automate Microsoft Word](http://brandonzeider.me/2010/microsoft-net/convert-word-to-pdf/) (if you can assume it will be on the target machine) or use a standalone .Net library, e.g.

- [WordGlue](http://www.websupergoo.com/wordglue-1.htm) (commercial)
- [PDF-Metamorphosis](http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-metamorphosis/) (commercial)
- [ExpertPDF](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/rtf-to-pdf.aspx) (commercial)
- [etc.](http://tinyurl.com/rtf2pdf)

Comment: I need to export it to pdf

Comment: @Ngeunpo see SO answer Convert RTF to PDF format http://stackoverflow.com/a/21747316/2012417 & Free RTF to PDF .NET component or tool? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5596782/2012417

Comment: @Ngeunpo you may also want to look at commercial offerings like http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-metamorphosis/ or http://www.html-to-pdf.net/rtf-to-pdf.aspx

Comment: as you said, it works fine with .rtf format. Can you help me on the conversion step [Rtf to Pdf]

Comment: @Ngeunpo you can either use Microsoft Word automation or an RTF to PDF library, I've updated the answer with some details